# How to handle browser refresh in vuejs applications

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Been playing around with vuejs which is awesome. Wondering if there is any suggestion on how to handle browser refreshes? How do we retain data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question i guess is:"how to get data when browser have been refreshed?",maybe you can try these method:

- [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
- [Cookie](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/Cookie)

for example,use **localstorage** to put and get data:

```
//before refresh,set data to LocalStorage
localStorage.setItem("foo","i am foo")

//when browser refreshed,get data back
localStorage.getItem("foo") // get:"i am foo"
```

Comment: Thanks it works, But I am exited to knew if is there any thing in Vue js default or module which manage this kind of page refresh things.

Answer (score 1):

Like Kaicui said. Question is more about persisting data in vuejs app.
Maybe you can try [vue-session](https://github.com/victorsferreira/vue-session)

---

```
this.$session.start()
this.$session.set('token', 0000)
this.$session.get('token')
```

it is really easy to use.